# Is there an opensource "MSWord doc to PDF" convert library

Tags: iphone, pdf, ms-word, open-source, doc

I am trying to convert word(.doc) into PDF on iOS device. Is there an opensource solution where I can use as a C/C++ lib or something?

Answer (score 2):

There really is no conveniently open-source library that will do this for you: you may get some mileage out of [WvWare](http://wvware.sourceforge.net/wvWare.html) but I've never seen it used on iOS and I'm not sure what platform dependencies it may need.

Answer (score 0):

If your iphone is connected to the net, then you can call a [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) web service to do it.  You need to sign up though.